Excel VBA .Range as a variable and looping
The attached is a VERY simple workbook of a timesheet program I am working on.  I am trying to figure out how to possibly use the .Range(variable).whatever where the variable could be made a loop.  I need to loop from 1 to 7 for days of the week and have many variables.  The Start and Stop in the attached are just for example.  I need the variables to be global constants as they feed other subroutines or functions.  I have the hard coded variables remarked out that worked but was hoping to take the variable prefix and do a for loop to concatenate together with the number to reduce the number of lines.
I tried the hard coded which works and tried the attached code with a few variations of using a temp string variable that I join and then use the temp.
The following code is in Module1
'public variables are used in actual project since variables can be used in other routines`  
Public Const Start1 As String = "B2:B7"
Public Const Stop1 As String = "C2:C7" 
Public Const Start2 As String = "D2:D7" 
Public Const Stop2 As String = "E2:E7"

The following code is on Worksheet Main, where cell B1 has a dropdown with the values Bold and Not Bold are located. There are two other Worksheets, one named TS1 and the other TS2.  The code that is remarked out works, the For loop gives a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range''' of object '_Worksheet' failed.  I have tried several variations.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim x As Long


If Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    'nothing
ElseIf Target = "Bold" Then
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'sht.Range(Start1).Font.Bold = True
        'sht.Range(Stop1).Font.Bold = True
        'sht.Range(Start2).Font.Bold = True
        'sht.Range(Stop2).Font.Bold = True
        For x = 1 To 2
            sht.Range("Start" & x).Font.Bold = True
            sht.Range("Stop" & x).Font.Bold = True
        Next x
    Next sht
    MsgBox "Text bold is on"

ElseIf Target = "Not Bold" Then
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'sht.Range(Start1).Font.Bold = False
        'sht.Range(Stop1).Font.Bold = False
        'sht.Range(Start2).Font.Bold = False
        'sht.Range(Stop2).Font.Bold = False
        For x = 1 To 2
            sht.Range("Start" & x).Font.Bold = False
            sht.Range("Stop" & x).Font.Bold = False
        Next x
    Next sht
    MsgBox "Text bold is off"
End If

End Sub

Updated 6/19/2024, I tried the suggestion from Tim in my sample file which worked.  Now when implementing it seems to not be calling the function, the debug.print is never happening.  I have other functions that I have written that are working and being called correctly.  I am only showing the function for the StartRange.
Public Const NUM_RANGES As Long = 7 'loop through days of week
'Return a range from `ws` indexed by `rngNum`
Function StartRange(ws As Worksheet, rngNum As Long)
    Debug.Print ws.Name, rngNum, DayLoopOffset
    Set StartRange = ws.Range("J13:J62").Offset(0, (rngNum - 1) * DayLoopOffset)
End Function

Sub zzzzzTimesheetClear()
'this routine clears the data from all the timesheets

Const strRangeName As String = "B13:B62"
Const strRangeShiftDifferential As String = "C13:C62"
Const strRangeNotes As String = "GB13:GB62"

Const strRangeServiceJob As String = "C9"

Dim strTemp, strInput As String
Dim answer, LunchDefault As Variant
Dim ClearEmployeeData As Boolean
Dim x As Long

On Error Resume Next

If Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 2) = "TS" Then

    ClearEmployeeData = False
    strInput = InputBox("You are about to clear ALL Timesheet data from " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".  Type CLEARDATA in all CAPS to clear the data." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  "Lunch Duration will be set to 0 min. if Service Job = Yes, otherwise Lunch Duration will be set to 30 min." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Check status bar for progress.", "WARNING! About to Clear All Data")

    If strInput = "CLEARDATA" Then
        'ask to clear employee name and shift differential
        answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to clear Employee Name and Shift Differential too?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Clear Employee and Shift Differential")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            ClearEmployeeData = True
        End If
        
        If Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(strRangeServiceJob).Value = "No" Then
            LunchDefault = "30 min."
        Else
            LunchDefault = "0 min."
        End If
    
        'used to not display error for checking which cells changed if a group or range
        boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True
        
        
        If Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 2) = "TS" Then 'if worksheet prefix is TS then it's a timesheet and should be processed
            Application.StatusBar = "Clearing data from " & ActiveSheet.Name
            If ClearEmployeeData = True Then
                Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(strRangeName).Value = ""
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(strRangeShiftDifferential).Value = ""
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
            End If
            
            For x = 1 To NUM_RANGES
                PLARange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = "No"
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                StartRange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = ""
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                LunchRange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = LunchDefault
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                StopRange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = ""
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                STAdjustRange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = 0
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                OTAdjustRange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = 0
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
                DTAdjustRange(ActiveSheet.Name, x).Value = 0
                boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
            Next x
            Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(strRangeNotes).Value = ""
            boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = True 'must set on each change due to change event setting back to False when complete
        End If
        MsgBox "ALL data was cleared from ALL timesheets" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Lunch Duration set to " & LunchDefault, vbCritical, "ALL DATA CLEARED"
    Else
        MsgBox "CLEARDATA not entered, timesheet data not cleared", vbInformation, "Entry Error"
    End If
ElseIf Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 2) <> "TS" Then
    MsgBox "Not on actual timesheet, please select a timesheet.", vbCritical, "Wrong Worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

Done:

boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = False
Application.StatusBar = False

Exit Sub

ErrMsg:

MsgBox "There seems to be an error" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & " at line " & Erl
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.StatusBar = False
boolClearingTimesheetSkipError = False
On Error GoTo -1


End Sub


You can't turn a string into a variable name. There is no relation between a string and the name you've assigned to a variable. Instead of that, make an array and loop through the elements of the array. Dim StartArr() as String: StartArr = Split("B2:B7,D2:D7",",") and then For Each Start in StartArr

Here's one suggestion since your ranges seem to follow a pattern:
Regular module:
Public Const NUM_RANGES As Long = 7

'Return a range from `ws` indexed by `rngNum`
Public Function StartRange(ws As Worksheet, rngNum As Long)
    Set StartRange = ws.Range("B2:B7").Offset(0, (rngNum - 1) * 2)
End Function

Public Function StopRange(ws As Worksheet, rngNum As Long)
    Set StopRange = ws.Range("C2:C7").Offset(0, (rngNum - 1) * 2)
End Function

Worksheet module:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sht As Worksheet, x As Long, c As Range, v, isBold As Boolean

    Set c = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1"))
    If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub     'no thing to do here

    Select Case c.Value
        Case "Bold": isBold = True
        Case "Not Bold": isBold = False
        Case Else: Exit Sub         'not a useable value
    End Select
    
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For x = 1 To NUM_RANGES
            StartRange(sht, x).Font.Bold = isBold
            StopRange(sht, x).Font.Bold = isBold
        Next x
    Next sht
    MsgBox "Text bold is " & IIf(isBold, "on", "off")
    
End If


Tim, that seems to work perfectly and is very simple.  Thanks!

Tim, worked great in my sample but then for some reason it does not seem to be calling these new functions.  I am getting calls to other functions I have written.  I'll have to dig into that.... :)

"it does not seem to be calling these new functions" - I'm not sure what you mean by that

Tim, I call the function(s) (StartRange, StopRange and a few others I added) but nothing is happening.  I added a debug.print to see if the call is getting inside the function and nothing prints.  It's weird and I am getting no errors.

Maybe edit your question to add an example of what’s not working?

Tim, I updated a section above dated 6/19/2024 to show the code sample.  I only listed one of the functions.

On Error Resume Next you can't know what's going wrong in your code if you have this in place. It may be silently skipping lines and you'd never know its failing. Comment it out and see what changes.

Tim :) I looked at that no telling how many times.... I had ActiveSheet.Name and it only needed to be ActiveSheet to pass the name.  It's strange how sometimes you need the .Name and sometimes you don't...  Thanks for catching that......

A Worksheet Change: Choose Bold Font From Drop-Down

The error is occurring because there is no range named Start1 ("Start" & x).

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ChooseBoldFont Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1
Option Explicit

Public Const START_COLUMN_ADDRESSES As String = "B2:B7,D2:D7"
Public Const END_COLUMN_ADDRESSES As String = "C2:C7,E2:E7"
Private Const FONT_BOLD_DROP_DOWN_CELL_ADDRESS = "B1"

Sub ChooseBoldFont(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim BoldStrings() As Variant: BoldStrings = VBA.Array("Bold", "Not Bold")
    Dim BoldStates() As Variant: BoldStates = VBA.Array(True, False)
    Dim BoldSwitches() As Variant: BoldSwitches = VBA.Array("on", "off")
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim scell As Range:
    Set scell = Intersect(sws.Range(FONT_BOLD_DROP_DOWN_CELL_ADDRESS), Target)
    If scell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim BoldString As String: BoldString = CStr(scell.Value)
    
    Dim Index As Variant: Index = Application.Match(BoldString, BoldStrings, 0)
    If IsError(Index) Then Exit Sub
    
    Index = Index - 1 ' since 'BoldStrings' is zero-based, ...
    ' ... while 'Application.Match' returns a one-based index
    
    Dim BoldState As Boolean: BoldState = BoldStates(Index)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    
    For Each dws In sws.Parent.Worksheets
        ' Set/unset bold font.
        Union(dws.Range(START_COLUMN_ADDRESSES), _
            dws.Range(END_COLUMN_ADDRESSES)).Font.Bold = BoldState
        
'        ' Loop Examples
'
'        Dim Starts() As String: Starts = Split(START_COLUMN_ADDRESSES, ",")
'        Dim Ends() As String: Ends = Split(END_COLUMN_ADDRESSES, ",")
'
'        Dim drg As Range, i As Long
'
'        ' Loop1
'        Debug.Print "Loop1: when doing something different to each Start and End"
'        For i = 0 To UBound(Starts)
'            Debug.Print i, Starts(i), Ends(i)
'        Next i
'
'        ' Loop2
'        Debug.Print "Loop2: when doing something to each range from Start to End"
'        For i = 0 To UBound(Starts)
'            Set drg = dws.Range(Starts(i), Ends(i))
'            'drg.Font.Bold = BoldState
'            Debug.Print i, drg.Address(0, 0)
'        Next i
    
    Next dws
        
    MsgBox "Text bold is " & BoldSwitches(Index) & ".", vbInformation
        
End Sub


VBasic2008, thanks for your quick reply.  I had first tried what Tim posted above and it seems to be working.  Thanks again.
